# Indices in Neo4j - questions and doubts

Tags: neo4j

The only indices that I know about them are indices on properties (these indices are created on particular labels (node types)). I have some doubts, however.

1. Are there exists indices on edges/relationships?
2. I often read that Neo4j leveraged Lucene Index. Is it still used? What is aim?
3. Are there exists any other indicses than indices on properties?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j has two indexing systems.

The more modern one is referred to as "schema indexes", and these are the ones that are automatic and apply to properties of a given label for quick lookup by those properties when the given properties and label are provided within a query. This does not currently support indexing of relationship properties. These started out based on lucene, but we've gradually replaced the implementation with our own native indexing solution. Discussion of these, as well as any noteworthy information and limitations, can be found in our [index configuration documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/).

The other indexing system is an older manual system that is called "explicit indexes", though this has previously been called "manual indexes". This is also based on lucene, but these are not automatic -- it is up to the user to manually add or remove entries to the index and keep them up to date when data in the database changes. This makes usage and maintenance cumbersome, and we recommend avoid using this system if possible.

[Built-in procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#explicit-indexes-procedures) are the means to create and lookup using explicit indexes, as these are never used automatically under the hood (as opposed to schema indexes). [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_manual_indexes_2) also offers various means of interfacing with explicit indexes.

The main reason one would use explicit indexes is because you are able to create an index on relationships for properties and get fast lookup when querying the index. This also allows for a full text lookup across multiple labels and properties, provided the index has been configured in such a way.

Separate from all of these, it should be noted that usage of labels is itself a kind of index, as it provides quick access to all nodes with the given label.

Comment: What about Lucene index? Is it past?

Comment: It's in the process of being replaced. [This section in the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/#index-configuration-native-indexes) says which indexes are native instead of lucene-based.